# Русские символы в waitKey(0) OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, locale

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу, где требуется вводить русские символы, но waitkey их не воспринимает в принципе - выводит кракозябры. Как я понял, waitkey воспринимает только символы ASCII, так вот как сделать, чтобы читались и русские символы?

```
key = cv2.waitKey()
print(key ,chr(key))
```

Выводит что-то типа:

```
224 à
243 ó
244 ô
247 ÷
239 ï
232 è
229 å
235 ë
```

Для разных русских букв.

Answer (score 0):

Я пришел к тому, что скорее всего нет возможности реализовать с помощью чистого opencv - он просто отказывается работать с символами non ascii, причем не только метод waitKey. Решил проблему путем добавления модуля [pynput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynput). Теперь русские символы считываются корректно.